# Chocolatey - This package does not support 64 bit architecture

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I have created my first two Chocolatey packages. Both of them bundle the installer in the .nupkg. I am testing the packages by installing them from disk. The first package works perfectly fine. The second package, however, gives me the following error:

> ERROR: This package does not support 64 bit architecture.

Both of these packages are installing applications that target x86 architecture so the error seems erroneous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found [this](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting#error-this-package-does-not-support-64-bit-architecture) almost immediately after posting my question. Not sure how I did not find it the first time around.

> This message is from https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/527 - it is when the url value chosen is empty.

Double checking my script showed I had a typo in the variable name I was passing to the url parameter which resulted in passing a null value.